# Angular 12 unit test, spy a function inside subscribe

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular12

I'm subscribing to a behavior subject in onInit and based on the result I'm calling a function. My code is like

```
subscription = new Subscription();
constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.myService.event.subscribe(response => {
    if(response){
       this.myFunction();
    }
  });
}
myFunction() {}
```

and I'm test this by trying like below

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let event = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ], imports: [

      ], providers: [{
        provide: MyService, useValue: {
          event: event
        }
      }]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call myFunction', (done) => {
    const myService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
    myService.event.next(true);
    component.ngOnInit();
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'myFunction');
    myService.event.subscribe((event: boolean) => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    })
  });
});
```

and I'm getting my spy is not called. Please help me to fix my code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're spying too late it seems.

Try the following:

```
// !! Spy first
const spy = spyOn(component, 'myFunction');
// !! Then call ngOnInit
component.ngOnInit();
```

Edit
Try with `fakeAsync` and `tick`.

```
it('should call myFunction, fakeAsync(() => {
  const myService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService);
  myService.event.next(true);
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'myFunction');
  
  component.ngOnInit();
  
  tick();

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

The `fakeAsync/tick` should hopefully wait until the `subscribe` is done before moving on to the `expect`.

Comment: tried that as well